# Grabbing certain columns from the rows that the MAX value occurred

Tags: sql, oracle

So i am trying to insert only the rows that are correlated to the HOUR where the MAX value occurred . However I am grouping by Day, and later on will be grouping on week, month, year, etc. Is my approach correct? The reason I am using a subquery is because I need to grab the value that goes into the HR column but adding it to the GROUP BY will mess up my daily groupings (if that makes sense). I need certain values from those columns to insert with a Stored Procedure that I wrote.  Is the query I have below on the right track? Thanks in Advance

Below is some sample data:

```
VALUE_ID      VALUE     HR                           VALUE_TYPE   OFFSET  DATA_CODE
   1            75      DEC-25-2018 01:00:00 AM      Bananas        1    HI
   2            10      DEC-25-2018 02:00:00 AM      Bananas        1    HI
   3             0      DEC-25-2018 03:00:00 AM      Bananas        1    HI
   4            77      DEC-25-2018 04:00:00 AM      Bananas        1    HI
   5            787     DEC-25-2018 05:00:00 PM      Bananas        1    HI
```

What I want:

```
VALUE_ID      VALUE     HR                           VALUE_TYPE   OFFSET  DATA_CODE
   5            787     DEC-25-2018 05:00:00 PM      Bananas        1    HI  


SELECT v.value AS MAX_VALUE
     , v.offset
     , v.data_code
     , v.hr
     , v.code
     , v.data_date
     , to_date(to_char(to_date(lpad(v.data_date, 7, 0), 'DDDYYYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY') as converted_date
FROM value v
inner join sub_value sv on v.value_id = sv.value_id
Where v.Value_id IN (select VALUE_ID from(
select  MAX(v.value) as MAX_VALUE
      , MAX(v.offset) as OFFSET
      , v.data_Code
      , MAX(v.value_id) as VALUE_ID
      , v.code
      , v.data_date
      , to_date(to_char(to_date(lpad(v.data_date, 7, 0), 'DDDYYYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY') as converted_date
  from value v
  inner join sub_value sv on v.value_id = sv.value_id;
```

**Also:** Would the process be the same for weekly MAX as well? (of course I am going to convert the date/timestamp to IW (week), but aside from that)

Comment: "correlated to the HOUR where the MAX value" Does this mean if the latest hour is 2018-01-01 5:30 pm we'd want to pick up any record between 2018-01-01 5:00 pm and 2018-01-01 5:59 pm?

Comment: all HRs being passed in are rounded to the nearest HOUR :)

Comment: Okay, in that case you'd want to swap Row_Number() for Rank() in Gordon's answer.

Comment: i don't think his answer fully addresses my whole issue though. I am trying to grab a column (HR) that is inside the outer query but is NOT being grouped by in the inner query where Im trying to find the MAX. In the outer query im trying to find the HR (And the rest of the columns) that are correlated to the MAX of each day (correct me if Im wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple method uses `row_number()` or `rank()`.  Here is an example, assuming you want the maximum for each `data_code`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by data_code order by value desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: is what I have also correct though? I am also grouping in the sub query wouldn't that add a few more layers of complexity to the query?